# Can we get React v16 as an option in Code Snippets?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-snippets

A few weeks ago the first stable version of [React v16](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v16.0.0), also known as *React Fiber* was released. This is a [complete re-write](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1716776591680069/react-16-a-look-inside-an-api-compatible-rewrite-of-our-frontend-ui-library/) of the core React architecture.

While React v16 and preceeding versions are identical in syntax, there are many differences under-the-hood. This introduces a plethora of new functionalities, bugs, warnings/errors, etc not found in the pre-v16 architecture.

Some may or may not be aware of these changes which might lead to users posting questions and answers that are accompanied with outdated Code Snippets.

I am aware that one could simply enter the appriopriate script links in the HTML section, but having this directly available would, not only prevent posting incompatible code, but probably also encourage users in posting [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) questions.

---

**TL;DR** - Please add React v16 to the list of React libraries in Code Snippets.

Comment: Vue would be nice as well.

Comment: Hardly any of the code snippet library versions have been updated at all for a long time; jQuery version is still 2.1.1 rather than 3.2.1.